# Windows 10 get error when runing process with default application

Tags: c#, process

i wrote below code to run my video file with default application and hook this process to my form.
the code run fine on windows 7 but on windows 10 get error to catch handle of video player process.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = @"c:\1.mp4"; //Path to locked file

        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.UseShellExecute = true;
        start.FileName = fileName;
        start.Verb = "open";

        Process p = Process.Start(start);
       SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);  //get error on windows 10        
    }
```

Comment: The code may have appeared to "run fine" but that was just by chance. See "Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?" - two notable quotes from it "Yes, it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws." and "the consequences can be very difficult to manage ... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree." - which is exactly the situation you're creating by hijacking some other processes window.

Comment: Forgot the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)